# get_nva_menu_locations returns only filled ones

Tags: menus

I need to get all nav menu locations. I tried the followings:

```
get_nav_menu_locations();
get_theme_mod('nav_menu_location');
```

both of them return only filled locations. I want all filled and empty locations.

Answer (score 0):

The real job of above functions aren't to get locations but to get locations and the menu they have inside. Something like `array($location1 => $menu_id1,);`. So these functions don't list empty locations. If you want to get all filled and empty locations you might want to add the following to your function.php file:

```
//// here is how you register your menu locations
function register_my_menus()
{
    register_nav_menus(
        array(
            'high-menu' => __('top menu'),
            'main-menu' => __('main menu'),
            'sec-menu' => __('sec menu'),
            'thrd-menu' => __('thrd menu'),
        )
    );
}
add_action('init', 'register_my_menus');

//// This is our new function to get all menu locations
function get_all_menus_locations(){
    //// sadly we have to init them like this. I couldn't find any other way yet
    $all_location = array(
        'high-menu',
        'main-menu',
        'sec-menu' ,
        'thrd-menu',        
    );
    //// this is the original function which gets only filled locations
    $locations = get_nav_menu_locations();
    
    //// this is our new variable. we will fill it by all locations
    $registered_nav_menus= [];
    foreach($all_locations as $location){
        if(isset($locations[$location])){
            //// if the location had a menu inside...
            $registered_nav_menus[$location] = $locations[$location];
        }
        else {
            ////if location was empty, set a new value for it.
            $registered_nav_menus[$location] = '';
        }
    }
    return $registered_nav_menus;
}
```

This isn't the solution I was looking for, but It's what I did. for now I work with it, If you have anything better, please share it.